# Updating column-entries when using groupby+apply iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use the groupby+apply methods on a dataframe and store the return-Values of the applied function in a new column.

The initial dataframe df is:

```
In[1]:  df
Out[1]: 
       tag    a   b 
0     tag1   15   1 
1     tag1   26   2 
2     tag2   20   2 
3     tag3   11   3 
4     tag3   15   3 
5     tag3   24   4
```

The groupby+apply procedure is the following:

```
In[2]:  grouped = df.groupby('tag')
In[3]:  df['a+b'] = grouped.get_group('tag1').apply(function,axis=1)
In[4]:  df
Out[4]:     
       tag    a   b  a+b
0     tag1   15   1   16
1     tag1   26   2   28
2     tag2   20   2  nan
3     tag3   11   3  nan
4     tag3   15   3  nan 
5     tag3   24   4  nan 
In[5]:  df['a+b'] = grouped.get_group('tag2').apply(function,axis=1) 
In[6]:  df
Out[6]:     
       tag    a   b  a+b
0     tag1   15   1  nan
1     tag1   26   2  nan
2     tag2   20   2   22
3     tag3   11   3   14
4     tag3   15   3  nan 
5     tag3   24   4  nan
```

First I chose to apply the function only to entries with 'tag1'. In the original case this is, because the used dataframe is huge and I am only interested in a small number of specific groups to apply the function to.

The problem which you can see from *In[5]* onwards, is that when repeating code from *In[3]* in *In[5]* for a different group, the entries in column 'a+b' for the group 'tag1' will get lost in this procedure.

How can I find a way to simply update column-entries of 'a+b' and not overwriting? Is there a best-practice example for this kind of problem?

Comment: It is getting lost in the procdure because you are recreating the column df['a+b'] have you tried using  a merge something like this df['a+b']=df['a+b'].merge(grouped.get_group('tag2').apply(function,axis=1) )

Comment: have you tried creating a new column for each group and then combining them at the end?

Comment: Thanks @PandasINC for the tip. Problem is that df['a+b'] is a pandas-Series and merge hence doesn't work. Also grouped.get_group('tag2') returns a Series with length according to the size of the picked group. However, I will try to solve this with Boolean-Masking.

Comment: @Kenan I believe this would be a working option. However, I found a different solution (see answers below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found works best. I use pandas.Series.update() which updates a single column of the Dataframe:

```
for key, item in grouped:

    series = grouped.get_group(key).apply(function,axis=1)

    if 'a+b' in df.columns :
        df['a+b'].update(series)
    else:
        df['a+b'] = series
```

This code works best, because I need the function to be applied iteratively to each group (or a specified set or groups) and not all groups at once. This is needed due to limited memory capacities and also because I need the information of the applied function only for a small number of groups.

Any comments on this code are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function just sums the columns along axis 1 so you can just sum and then filter the rows you want.

```
df.assign(ab=df.sum(axis=1)).loc[df['first'].isin(['tag1', 'tag2'])]

  first   a  b  ab
0  tag1  15  1  16
1  tag1  26  2  28
2  tag2  20  2  22
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a `groupby` in this case. You can save the tags you want to apply the function to, and than do something like this:

```
desired_tags = ['tag1', 'tag2']

df['a+b'] = (df[df['tag'].isin(desired_tags)]
             .apply(function, axis=1))
```

The output is as follows:

```
    tag   a  b   a+b
0  tag1  15  1  16.0
1  tag1  26  2  28.0
2  tag2  20  2  22.0
3  tag2  11  3  14.0
4  tag3  15  3   NaN
5  tag3  24  4   NaN
```

I'm assuming your `function` is something like:

```
function = lambda df: df['a'] + df['b']
```

This way you can run the command just once

Comment: thanks for your comment- however, I would like to be able to apply the function one group after the other, not all at once. This is because of limited memory and long run-times when applying function.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily select non-null part of `df['a+b']` column by doing so:

```
df.loc[df['a+b'].isnull(), 'a+b'] = grouped.get_group('tag2').apply(function, axis=1)
```